# Force the browser to cache a .php

Tags: php, http-headers

I need the browser to cache a large, mostly static .php file. I open it via ajax and want to add it to the current page.

After some research if found [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-caching-headers/)

```
$seconds_to_cache = 3600;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache");
```

This works for IE, but not for chrome and firefox.

Here is the request

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie  PHPSESSID=5dkvr42f4it8pnnnqpesj6l413
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/mifa/Suche.php
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
charset utf-8
```

and here the response header

```
Cache-Control   max-age=3600
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Thu, 05 Jul 2012 15:28:22 GMT
Expires Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:28:22 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=91
Pragma  cache
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.8
```

What do i need to change?

**EDIT**

Apparently, only IE does not append the Cache-Control max-age=0 to the request.

Here is the JS Function of the request

```
url = "includes/Orte.php";
obj.onreadystatechange = rState;
obj.open("GET", url, true);
obj.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "");
obj.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "");
obj.setRequestHeader("charset", "utf-8");
obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
obj.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
obj.send();

function rState(){
    if(obj.readyState == 4){
        if (obj.status == 200){
            //alert("Response Text Ajax:\n" + obj.responseText + "\nEnd Response Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may achieve this by sending a `HTTP 304 Not modified` at the second consequent request to make sure the browser does not ask again. I believe that some browsers do request files again although you set a correct cache date/time etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header in the request means that you asked your browser to refresh the page, so he just ignores the cache.

Access the page without hitting refresh (e.g. focus the address bar and hit enter) to avoid this.

Also, if the page is on an HTTPS URL, you may have to add `public` to the Cache-Control header, else some browsers won't cache it.

Comment: You re right, only IE does not append the max-age=0.

How do i fix this? I posted the code of JS above. Do you know where ff and chrome inserts that header?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that come to mind are the last modified header, and using .htaccess cache control. The latter is for broad types but you can use it just for one folder, with that file in a folder by itself.

```
header("Last-Modified: ... ");
```

Comment: `Last-Modified` will trigger the browser into sending a `If-Modified-Since` in its next request; which the script will have to parse and maybe reply with a `304 Not Modified` status. This will prevent the browser from downloading the whole content, but not from doing a request.